# Converting numbers that start with zeros

Tags: python

Can anyone explain the following to me please.

```
i = 700001
z = str(i % 100000)
```

z='1', but i want to z='00001'. How i can get it?

Comment: What do you want to do if `i = 2700001`? Do you want `00001` or `000001`? In other words, your question is ill-formed.

Comment: in your program, python will first evaluate (700001 % 100000) to 1, then compute str(1). You have to understand that the str function does not care about were its args come from. It will convert them as a string (with the simplest representation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution:

```
>>> z.zfill(5)
'00001'
```

Answer (score 6):

Do this:

```
z = '{:05}'.format(i % 100000)
```

Comment: I thought I knew Python fairly well, but I have to say that I'm shocked at how many different ways there are to do this one simple thing, some of which I've never seen before.

Comment: Obligatory link the documentation for format : http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax (not the best part of the doc, by the way).

Answer (score 2):

Use [`str.rjust`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust)

```
>>> s = '1'
>>> s.rjust(5, '0')
'00001'
```

Comment: Note that `str.rjust()`, in contrast to `str.zfill()`, isn't sign-aware.

Answer (score 2):

See [Python string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations):

```
z = '%05d'%(i % 100000)
```

Comment: +1 This is the way I would naturally do it. However it's important to note the very different meanings of the `%` sign.